# 'list iterator not dereferencable'

Tags: c++, list, stl

```
   #include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

#include <list> 


//A queue for the working set 
//x,y co-ords of the square, path length so far 
struct square {
    int x;
    int y; 
    int path_length;
};

list<square> workingset; 


//A 2D array of ints to represent the board (duplicates list)
int board[10][10]; 

void generatelegalmove(square node, int x_offset, int y_offset); 
void printboard(); 

void main()
{
    //Initialises the board 
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    //The goal position - a number we will never reach 
    board[8][8] = 1337; 

    bool goal_found = false; 

    //Sets up initial position 
    square temp = {3, 7, 1}; 

    //Put initial position in working set and duplicates list
    workingset.push_back(temp); 
    board[3][7] = 1; 

    //Loop (until a goal is found)
    while(!goal_found)
    {
        //Get the head node from the working set
        square nodetocheck = workingset.front();

        //Exit if the goal has been found
        if(board[nodetocheck.x][nodetocheck.y] == 1337)
        {
            goal_found = true;
            break; 
        }

        //Generate the legal moves 
        generatelegalmove(nodetocheck, -1, 0); //One square to the left
        generatelegalmove(nodetocheck, 0, -1); //One square up
        generatelegalmove(nodetocheck, 1, 0); //One square to the right
        generatelegalmove(nodetocheck, 0, 1); //One square down


        if(!workingset.empty())
        {
                //workingset.pop_front();
        }

    //End Loop
    }

    //Print the Board 
    printboard();
    while(true);

    //Trace back and print Trace back (once implemented) 

    //Print other info 

}


void generatelegalmove(square node, int x_offset, int y_offset)
{
    node.x = node.x + x_offset;
    node.y = node.y + y_offset; 
    node.path_length = node.path_length+1; 
    //Is this square on the board
    if((node.x >= 0) && 
       (node.x < 10) && 
       (node.y >= 0) && 
       (node.y < 10) && 
       //Is this square empty
       (board[node.x][node.y] == 0))
    {

        workingset.push_back(node);
        board[node.x][node.y] = node.path_length; 
        //Add to working set
        //Add to duplicates list 
    }
    //(If a graphical animation is added, do it here, by printing the new board after each one, then sleeping for a few seconds) 
}
```

I get the runtime error 'list iterator not dereferencable'.

I'm assuming this is to do with `workingset.pop_front()` being called from within the while loop, but I'm not sure what I should do to remedy this.

Each loop, I want to get the node from the front of the list, work with it a little, then remove that node from the list.

This is the code for generatelegalmove() - as you can see, if the new square is on the board (i.e. within the range of 0-9 in both dimensions of the array, and the square is empty) it will add this new node to the working set and the board[][] (which is effectively a duplicates list in effect)

Comment: It would be worth to add the declaration of the used variable workingset.

Comment: Which particular line of the code you posted causes this error? Is it a compiler error or run-time error (debug check)?

Comment: What do you mean? It's added earlier in the program, it's a list of the struct square. I didn't add the entirety of my code because it's long and I assumed things such as using the include for a list, declaring the bool goal_found, initialising board[][] and workingset etc. would be assumed... Or do you mean something else??

Comment: It's a Debug Error - and uhm, it says Line 207. But my program is only a little over 100 lines long...

Comment: it could be line 207 in some other class (for example in the code that is in `std::list`). You need to inspect the stack trace to locate the first frame in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Given the sample you have provided, I can see one thing wrong.  At the end of each loop iteration, you pop the front node.  However, you only exit out of your loop if `goal_found` is true, meaning the line:

```
square nodetocheck = workingset.front();
```

... could well access an empty working set.  Obviously you have calls to other functions here that might add nodes, but this might be a problem if no nodes existed.

EDIT: I believe your code is not adding another node because you are using the bitwise-and `&` operator instead of a logical-and `&&` operator, causing your working set not to gain nodes.

Comment: generatelegalnode() will almost always be adding a node to the set... You're right, I should absolutely only allow it to be popped if the list isn't empty, but i'm pretty positive it *can't* be empty until the goal state is found

Comment: (It's a representation of the Lee algorithm for pathfinding, the working set shouldn't be empty of things to try until the goal square is found, afaik)

Comment: calling front() or pop_front() on an empty set would generate a runtime error though. The user is getting a compiler error.

Comment: @ShimmerGeek, just out of interest, does it complete a single iteration of that loop before the error is encountered?  E.g, do you have nodes when you enter the loop?  Can we also see the contents of `generatelegalmove` and see how it interacts with the working set?

Comment: I don't understand why it's telling me 'list iterator not dereferencable' either - I'm not using an iterator myself at least, I'm accessing the node at the top of the list directly, both to access it and remove it

Comment: @ShimmerGeek, also when you set `goal_found` to true, you can just `break;` out of the loop at that point and skip the unnecessary generation of legal moves you won't be needing. :)

Comment: If I don't remove the node from the working set, the rest of the program works fine; it just loops endlessly but since it only checks the first node over and over it will never end. (Oh, and yes, I put one node in the list before the loop)

Comment: @ShimmerGeek, let's take a look at `generatelegalmove`. :)

Comment: I've seen this error message at runtime when trying to dereference an iterator that points at `foo.end()`, i.e., behind the last entry. I'm with Moo-Juice here, add a bail-out if `workingset.empty()` and see if the message stays there. (And, BTW: You're talking about a “compiler error” at one place and a “Debug Error”, which I assume is a runtime error, at another place. You should be able to edit your question to clarify what kind of error you get.)

Comment: There ya go :) Hope it helps a little, have added in break; too, and it will only pop it off if the list isn't empty :)

Comment: I added the bail-out but it still happens; and sorry, I'll edit that (I'm still quite a new programmer - early second year at University - and I kinda suck at remembering terms correctly sometimes; sorry)

Comment: @ShimmerGeek, I think those `&` s are supposed to be `&&`  if you actually mean `AND` rather than a bit-operation...

Comment: @ShimmerGeek can you update both code-samples with what you have now?

Comment: Will do. I'll add the stuff at the start too, in case it helps.

Comment: Okay, that's all my code, aside from the printboard() function which works correctly and just includes a couple of loops and some couts. The while(true) at the end is just to make the printouts appear indefinitely.

Comment: @ShimmerGeek, that `if(!workingset.empty())` line needs to be checked before you access `front()`.  So, add something like this right after `while(true)` : `if(workingset.empty()) break;` to exit the loop.  Your goal may not be found, but that's another problem :)

Comment: @ShimmerGeek, better yet, change the loop to: `while(!goal_found && !workingset.empty())`.